# Additional information: Procedure or function insertimi has too many arguments specified( C# SQL insertion process)

Tags: c#, sql

I am working with a small POS application, but I ma having a problem during the insertion of data from win form to SQL database . To be more clearly I get this kind of error "Additional information: Procedure or function insertimi has too many arguments specified."
.
The code I am using to insert data is showed below:

```
          conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertimi", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@shenime", txtshenime.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", DateTime.Now));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@kasieri", lbluser.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emri_sh", lblshitesiemri.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@niptsh", int.Parse(lblshitesinipt.Text)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@adresash", lbladresashitesi.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@telefonish", lblshitesitelefon.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emri_b", cmbbleresi.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@niptb", lblbleresinipt.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@adresab", lblbleresiadresa.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@telefonib", lblbleresitelefoni.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nentotali", lblnentotali.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vleratvsh", lblvleratvsh.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@zbritja", txtzbritja.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totali", lbltotali.Text));

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgprofatura.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@barkodi", row.Cells[0].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emertimi", row.Cells[1].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sasia", row.Cells[3].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cmimi", row.Cells[2].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totaliPCS", row.Cells[5].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tvsh", row.Cells[4].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vleratvshpcs", row.Cells[7].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@patvshpcs", row.Cells[6].Value));

                }
            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
            conn.Close();
            clear();
            kRIJOToolStripMenuItem.PerformClick();
        }
```

And the SP code:

```
     ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertimi]

    @shenime varchar(max),
    @data datetime,
    @kasieri varchar(50),
    @emri_sh varchar(50),
    @niptsh varchar(50),
    @adresash varchar(100),
    @telefonish varchar(50),
    @emri_b varchar(50),
    @niptb varchar(50),
    @adresab varchar(100),
    @telefonib varchar(50),
    @nentotali float,
    @zbritja float,
    @vleratvsh float,
    @totali float,
    @barkodi int,
    @emertimi varchar(200),
    @sasia int, 
    @cmimi float,
    @totaliPCS float,
    @tvsh float,
    @vleratvshpcs float,
    @patvshpcs float
    as


    declare @lastId int;
    insert into tblprofatura (Shenime,Data,Kasieri,Emri_sh,NIPT_sh,Adresa_sh,Telefoni_sh,Emri_b,NIPT_b,Adresa_b,Telefoni_b,Nentotali,Zbritja,VleraTVSH,Totali)


    values(@shenime,@data,@kasieri,@emri_sh,@niptsh,@adresash,@telefonish,@emri_b,@niptb,@adresab,@telefonib,@nentotali,@zbritja,@vleratvsh,@totali)
    set @lastId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();


    insert into tblproofatura_details(NR_F,Barkodi,Emertimi,Cmimi,Sasia,TVSH,Totali,PaTVSHpcs,VleraTVSHpcs)
    values (@lastId,@barkodi,@emertimi,@cmimi,@sasia,@tvsh,@totaliPCS,@patvshpcs,@vleratvsh)
```

What should i change in my C# code to fix the error? Maybe the loop code how I get the data from datagridview. If someone could help me , about this problem.

Thanks yo everyone

Comment: The error message is clear, there are too many parameters, but the actual problem is using this stored procedure in the first place. 14 parameters are way too many. Mixing them up is very easy. Why are you using a stored procedure for this INSERT? For starters, data isn't stored in grids, it's stored in collections, objects and data tables. You bind the data to the grid, and manage the data, not the grid rows. If you use DataTables or datasets, the DbDataAdapter you probably used to load the data can also perform updates and insertions

Comment: Might as well use AddWithValue if you're going to do that..

Comment: The issue you have sin the forloop.If it always is anew row.it'll keep adding them parameters

Answer (score 0):

Because of foreach loop, you are getting too many parameters being passed to the stored procedure. you can have this logic, inside foreach loop.

```cs
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgprofatura.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@shenime", txtshenime.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", DateTime.Now));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@kasieri", lbluser.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emri_sh", lblshitesiemri.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@niptsh", int.Parse(lblshitesinipt.Text)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@adresash", lbladresashitesi.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@telefonish", lblshitesitelefon.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emri_b", cmbbleresi.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@niptb", lblbleresinipt.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@adresab", lblbleresiadresa.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@telefonib", lblbleresitelefoni.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nentotali", lblnentotali.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vleratvsh", lblvleratvsh.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@zbritja", txtzbritja.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totali", lbltotali.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@barkodi", row.Cells[0].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emertimi", row.Cells[1].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sasia", row.Cells[3].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cmimi", row.Cells[2].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totaliPCS", row.Cells[5].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tvsh", row.Cells[4].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vleratvshpcs", row.Cells[7].Value));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@patvshpcs", row.Cells[6].Value));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
```

You do not need to add parameters everytime. You can map them once to command at the beginning before foreach loop and assign them every time in the foreach loop.

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add("@barkodi", SqlDbType.Int);
.
.
.

 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgprofatura.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                  cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = row.Cells[0].Value;
                      .
                      .
                      .
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
              }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware you can just set new values for existing parameters? No need to add them every time.. `cmd.Parameters["@shenime"].Value = txtshenime.Text;`

Comment: @CaiusJard, Yes. I am aware of. I just reformatted the code to clarify his problem. I will update my answer